# Review Triage CSS bug Stack Overflow

Tags: bug, design

Just noticed the upvote, downvote, and Timeline buttons hovering over the Review Status Panel, on the review/triage/xxxx page Stack Overflow.

The status panel which seems to be fixed positioned, gets behind only the Voting and Timeline icons only, and rest, even the Vote count comes behind the panel.\

Possibly the z-index needs to be changed.

Following is the screen shot:
[image: Faulty icons z-indexs]

Increasing the zoom level also found the same behaviour happening for new contributor tag:
[image: Screen shot]

Also the same problem seems to appear with the tags associated with the question on the same page:

[image: Faulty tag icons z-index]

Comment: Temporarily fixed with my userscript [ReviewQueueHelper](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts/blob/master/ReviewQueueHelper.user.js)